# Adding node to the beginning of Linked List

Tags: c, list, pointers, linked-list, malloc

I am trying to manipulate linked list and the task is to add the node to the beginning of the Linked List.

fl_newEmpty() function returns a pointer to an
empty list , i don't know if i have written it correct.

fl_show() just prints each node

I should get following output. The addresses can be different

```
------- Show floatList : list made by FL_add ---------
0 : 0x7fad88404c10 7.000000 0x7fad88404c00
1 : 0x7fad88404c00 5.000000 0x7fad88404bf0
2 : 0x7fad88404bf0 3.000000 0x0
3 elements in all.
```

But i get this:  I don't know why node in 2 index is pointing to the node in 3 index :(

```
------- Show floatList : list made by FL_add ---------
0   : 0x1e1a2c0 7.000000 0x1e1a2a0
1   : 0x1e1a2a0 5.000000 0x1e1a280
2   : 0x1e1a280 3.000000 0x1e1a260
3   : 0x1e1a260 0.000000 (nil)
4 elements in all
```

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct floatList
{
    float val;
    struct floatList *next;
};

void FL_show(struct floatList *plist, char *label)
{
    // check if plist is empty
    if (plist == NULL)
    {
        printf("The list is empty!\n");
    }

    struct floatList *pf;
    pf = plist;

    int count = 0; // for checking the total number of elements in the list
    printf("------- Show floatList : %s ---------\n", label);
    for(int i = 0 ; pf!= NULL ; i++){
        count++;
        printf("%d\t: %p %f %p\n",i, pf, pf->val, pf->next);
        pf = pf->next;
    }
    printf("%d elements in all\n",count);
}

struct floatList *FL_newEmpty()
{
    struct floatList *new_list = (struct floatList *)malloc(sizeof(struct floatList));
    new_list->next = NULL;
    return new_list;
}

struct floatList* FL_add(struct floatList *plist, float val)
{
    struct floatList *new_list = (struct floatList*)malloc(sizeof(struct floatList));
    new_list->next = plist;
    new_list->val = val;
    return new_list;
}



int main(){

    struct floatList *plist;
    plist = FL_newEmpty();
    plist = FL_add(plist,3);
    plist = FL_add(plist,5);
    plist = FL_add(plist,7);
    FL_show(plist,"list made by FL_add");
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extra node is because of the completely unnecessary function `FL_newEmpty()` that you have added to your program and are using.

Simply delete this function and don't call it.

```
int main(){
    struct floatList *plist;
    plist = FL_add(NULL,3);
    plist = FL_add(plist,5);
    plist = FL_add(plist,7);
    FL_show(plist,"list made by FL_add");
    return 0;
}
```

The null pointer is your empty list already; you can add to it with `FL_add(NULL, 3)`.  There is no need to have a constructor which creates a new empty list, because there is only one empty list: the value `(struct floatList *) 0`. This is just a null pointer, requiring no memory allocation. If you like, you could make a macro for it:

```
#define NULL_FLOATLIST ((struct floatList *) NULL)
```

Then:

```
plist = FL_add(NULL_FLOATLIST, 3.0);
```

If some hapless CS instructor made it mandatory that there be a `FL_newEmpty()` function, we can provide it like this:

```
#define FL_newEmpty() ((struct floatList *) NULL)
```

or as a trivial function:

```
struct floatList *FL_newEmpty()
{
    return NULL;
}
```

However, the word `new` in the name is clearly misleading; it's always returning the same null pointer!

The `(nil)` syntax you are seeing instead of `0x00000000` is just a feature of the `%p` conversion specifier of your particular C library. I know that the GNU C library prints null pointers this way, and perhaps others. The C standard doesn't specify what the output of `%p` looks like; it says s:

> The argument shall be a pointer to void. The value of the pointer is converted to a sequence of printing characters, in an implementation-defined manner.

If you want to see consistent `0x` notation, what you can do is cast the pointer to `intptr_t`, and then use the `PRIxPTR` conversion specifier to print that value:

```
#include <inttypes.h>

...

    printf("%d\t: 0x%" PRIxPTR " %f 0x%" PRIxPTR "\n", i,
           (intptr_t) pf, pf->val, (intptr_t) pf->next);
```

`PRIxPTR` is a macro from `<inttypes.h>` which expands to a conversion specifier suitable for an `intptr_t` value, for rendering it in hexadecimal. This is needed because `intptr_t` is a `typedef` name; we don't know what integer type it is. The macro does not provide the leading `%` character, only the conversion specifier itself. In our example, we can see why that is useful: we are able to sneak in the `#` modifier after the `%` to get the `0x` prefix.

Incidentally, the `FL_newempty` function is not only useless, but it has a problem: it is failing to initialize the floating-point data. The `0.0` you are seeing in the output is just a fluke due to the memory having come out of `malloc` with all-zero bytes, which `malloc` does not guarantee.

Comment: Can i use somehow FL_newEmpty() function? because its mandatory

Comment: Yes; I will add that to the answer.

Comment: and also i can not change what i have written in main, its mandatory to be like this

Comment: Thank you very much)) It works now. I hope my instructor won't see it :D

Comment: @UglyMicha Maybe that's part of the lesson: you're supposed to come to the conclusion that the `FL_newEmpty` must actually just return a null pointer.  Or else the instructor is expecting a different style of linked list, that is a bag-like object (similar to a Python list and whatnot).

Comment: actually yes, i only have prototypes of functions, and i should come up with  solutions

Comment: OK, that makes sense. But the prototypes include a return value. The caller of `FL_add` must retain the return value and treat that as the new list.  That will still work with a "bag-like container" list implementation; it's just that the return value will never change. What won't work is that the previous list does not exist in that case; programs relying on adding an element to make a 4 element list, while continuing to rely on using the 3 element list, will not work. Those two are the same object: the (now) 4 element list.

Comment: yes, i got it. So its better to have void FL_add function ?

Comment: Well, you can't change that; you were given the API declarations. I'm just saying that there are choices for how to choose semantics for those API declarations, and programs can depend on those choices, so they don't work with other choices. (Maybe the instructor specified some of that.)